# Local Maxima for a Sum of two Gaussian functions

Tags: derivatives, summation, normal-distribution, maxima-minima, gaussian

Given that we have a function $f(x)$ which is a sum of two arbitrary Gaussian functions such that:
$$
f(x) = A_{1} e^{-\frac{(x - \mu_{1})^{2}}{2\sigma_{1}^{2}}} + A_{2} e^{-\frac{(x - \mu_{2})^{2}}{2\sigma_{2}^{2}}}
$$
where weights $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$ are positive, and $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ denote the standard deviations of the Gaussian functions.

I have found out that there is no analytical solution in obtaining the local maxima of the function $f(x)$. However, I was wondering if anyone is aware of any way to approximate this problem analytically (and not numerically).

I basically need this for modelling a specific problem and I would like to see if there are any cool tricks or any theorems that may help me to do some rough approximations to simplify this problem.

Thanks,
Charis

Comment: Transcendental equations sometimes have analytical solutions. But usually such equations have certain numerical coefficients, not arbitrary $A_1$, $A_2$, etc.

Comment: Analytical consideration also can decrease number of independent parameters: for example, $x_0=\mu_1+\sigma_1 f\left(\frac{\mu_1-\mu_2}{\sigma_1},\frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2},\frac{A_2}{A_1}\right)$.

Comment: I am not quite sure what that means.

Comment: $f$ in my last comment is not $f$ from your problem. I should use another symbol. The maximum point $x_0$ depends on parameters of your function $f(x)$ which are $A_1$, $A_2$, $\sigma_1$, $\sigma_2$, $\mu_1$, $\mu_2$. In general case $x_0$ is function of six parameters: $x_0=g(A_1, A_2, \sigma_1, \sigma_2, \mu_1, \mu_2)$. Analytical consideration helps to express result through function of three parameters: $x_0=\mu_1+ \sigma_1 h(\frac{\mu_1-\mu_2}{\sigma_1}, \frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}, \frac{A_1}{A_2})$. I believe there are not closed-form expression for $h$, but you can tabulate this function